# Items being duplicated in the onClick of listview

Tags: android

I am storing some images(.jpg) and pdf(.pdf) in my app folder on the sdcard. Listview gets populated but when I am clicking on a pdf item in my listview, both jpg's and pdf's items are being shown in the listview many times.I need help in figuring out.Thanks

```
public class Data_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data_Class>{


    Context context;
    int ResourceLayoutId;
    ArrayList<Data_Class> data=null;

    public Data_Adapter(Context c,int r,ArrayList<Data_Class> dc)
    {
        super(c,r,dc);
        this.ResourceLayoutId=r;
        this.context=c;
        this.data=dc;

    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        View row=convertView;
        DataHolder holder=null;

        if(row==null)
          {
              LayoutInflater inflater= ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
              row=inflater.inflate(ResourceLayoutId, parent, false);
              holder=new DataHolder();
             holder.image=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image1);
             holder.txt=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textlist);
              row.setTag(holder);
          }
          else
          {

              holder=(DataHolder)row.getTag();

          }

          Data_Class dc=data.get(position);
          holder.txt.setText(dc.data);

          Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(data.get(position).get_path(), 100, 100);
          holder.image.setImageBitmap(bm);


          return row;    


    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

          Bitmap bm = null;
          // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
          final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
          options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
          BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

          // Calculate inSampleSize
          options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

          // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
          options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
          bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

          return bm;  
         }


    public int calculateInSampleSize(

            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            // Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
             if (width > height) {
              inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);   
             } else {
              inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);   
             }  
            }

            return inSampleSize;   
           }






    public class DataHolder
    {

        ImageView image;
        TextView txt;
    }

}
```

// in main activity

```
 private ListView listview1;
    private int check_view;
    private File targetDirectory;
    private File[] files;
    protected static  ArrayList<Data_Class> dataclass=new ArrayList<Data_Class>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    check_view = 0;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);
    listview1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.List1);

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String targetPath = path + "/AppName/";

    targetDirectory = new File(targetPath);
    files = targetDirectory.listFiles();

      for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
      {
          dataclass.add(new Data_Class(files[i].getName(),files[i].getAbsolutePath()));
      }

      Data_Adapter adapter=new Data_Adapter(this,R.layout.img,dataclass);
      listview1.setAdapter(adapter);

      listview1.setClickable(true);
      listview1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        Data_Class mData_Class = (Data_Class)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        String path = mData_Class.get_path();



           if(path.contains(".jpg")){

               String path3 = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

               Intent intent = new Intent();
               intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                       + "/AppName/" + path3), "image/*");
               startActivity(intent);

               //Toast.makeText(ListviewActivity.this, path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           }
                  if(path.contains(".pdf")){

               String path2 = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);


               File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/AppName/" +  path2);
               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
               intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
               Intent intent2 = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File");
               try {
                   startActivity(intent2);

               } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                   Toast.makeText(ListviewActivity.this, "No pdf viewer found. Install one. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }   


           }

        }

                  });


             }

  }
```

// Data_Class

```
public class Data_Class {

public String data;
public String pic;
public Data_Class()
{
    super();
}
public Data_Class(String d, String p)
{
    super();
    this.data=d;
    this.pic=p;
}

public String Get_Name()
{
    return data;
}

public String get_path()
{
    return pic;
}

void Set_Name(String s)
{
    data=s;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the previous data in the listview was not getting cleared before the next loading of listview. So every time the activity loads, I cleared the listview as below.Hope it helps someone in the future.

```
 adapter.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

do this because whenever you click on `ListView` item the `getView()` method is getting called so no need to add it again.

yout `getView()` should be like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 {

        View row=convertView;
        DataHolder holder=null;

        if(row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater= ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(ResourceLayoutId, parent, false);
            holder=new DataHolder();
            holder.image=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image1);
            holder.txt=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textlist);
            row.setTag(holder);

            Data_Class dc=data.get(position);
            holder.txt.setText(dc.data);

            Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(data.get(position).get_path(), 100, 100);
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(bm);


          }
          else
          {

              holder=(DataHolder)row.getTag();

          }
          return row;    

    }
```

Comment: tried, it's still populating repeated data in listview.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any issue in the code you posted above.

```
protected static  ArrayList<Data_Class> dataclass=new ArrayList<Data_Class>();
```

As you have declared "dataclass" as static make sure you are not modifying it in other part of the code.

Comment: I am not modifying the class. What I fail to understand is that why is the data in listview being repeated?

Comment: Number of items in listview = number of items in "dataclass" arraylist. what i mean to say is make sure static arraylist variable  dataclass is not modified when click event is performed on listview.

Comment: Another thing which I just noticed, as I scroll in the listview, the position of the items gets changed.

Comment: can you please post the entire code of main activity class and adapter  class

Comment: The entire code of main activity class and adapter class is above. I added the code for Data_Class as well. I really appreciate your input on this. Thanks

Comment: Right now by clicking on item in the list, all the items get duplicated.